# How to limit element heights to specific values ("stepped") based on content

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to achieve, I can't describe it better, "step-based heights" on a div? I made a little [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnjetmgo/) to display what I have.

My target is now, that every box has a height that's a multiple of 400px. So if a box with `height: auto;` would be 345px, it should be 400px, if it's between 400 and 800px it should be 800px and so on. Unfortunately I haven't found anything useful to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: You could use jquery to select all the desired elements, and then round their height css properties to a multiple of 400px;

Comment: I'd imagine that you need some sort of Javascript to update the containers once they're rendered. I don't think this can be done with CSS only (unless you explicitly define the height of the containers).

Comment: Client-side scripting or server-side class designation if the content is known.

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer and accept it. This way, it will be clear to other people facing a similar issue that this question has an alternative answer, even if it was not exactly what you were looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not an actual answer to my question. I will wait for a html/css solution to accept

Comment: [This question is being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308661/1858225).

Comment: @MichaelKunst This post has now been rolled back to its original state as a result of the proposed action based on this Meta discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308661/2827823. If you still want an answer on a html/css only solution, we recommend you add it as a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Here I put together a sample snippet which shows a very simple concept of keeping them <strike>equal high</strike> with a stepped height <strike>between 400, 800, 1200.</strike>

Todo: Update the script to either set the element or css dynamically instead of my fixed height. And if you want it to recalc on resize, you also need to subscribe to the very same event.

```js
function testHeight () {
  var scriptTag = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
  var parentTag = scriptTag.previousElementSibling;
  var childrenTags = parentTag.children;
  for (var i = 0; i < childrenTags.length; i++) {
    var childTag = childrenTags[i];
    childTag.style.height = "auto";
    childTag.style.height = (Math.ceil(parseInt(childTag.clientHeight) / 400) * 400) + "px";    
  }
}

testHeight();


(function() {

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeThrottler, false);

  var resizeTimeout;
  function resizeThrottler() {
    // ignore resize events as long as an actualResizeHandler execution is in the queue
    if ( !resizeTimeout ) {
      resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        resizeTimeout = null;
        actualResizeHandler();

        // The actualResizeHandler will execute at a rate of 15fps
      }, 66);
    }
  }

  function actualResizeHandler() {
    // handle the resize event
    testHeight();
  }

}());
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper div {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 400px;
}

.wrapper div:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div>Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ip</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ip</div>
</div>
```

If you would want all the boxes equally high, this version calc the height on the "wrapper" instead of looping each element.

```js
function testHeight () {
  var scriptTag = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
  var parentTag = scriptTag.previousElementSibling;
  parentTag.style.height = "auto";
  parentTag.style.height = (Math.ceil(parseInt(parentTag.clientHeight) / 400) * 400) + "px";
}

testHeight();


(function() {

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeThrottler, false);

  var resizeTimeout;
  function resizeThrottler() {
    // ignore resize events as long as an actualResizeHandler execution is in the queue
    if ( !resizeTimeout ) {
      resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        resizeTimeout = null;
        actualResizeHandler();

        // The actualResizeHandler will execute at a rate of 15fps
      }, 66);
    }
  }

  function actualResizeHandler() {
    // handle the resize event
    testHeight();
  }

}());
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper div {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper div:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div>Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ip</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ip</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not quite what I was looking for. If done with javascript, it should look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rnjetmgo/2/. Since in your answers, all the divs have the same height, but for 2 of them a height of 400 would be sufficient to contain all the content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using jQuery which sets each box to the nearest "400px step" height.

```js
$('div').each(resize);

function resize(){
    var height = $(this).css( "height" );
    var newHeight = Math.ceil(parseInt(height) / 400) * 400;
    $(this).css('height', newHeight+'px');
}
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ip</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ipsum 123 123 Lorem Ip</div>
```

Comment: This answer was originally edited into the question by the OQA/OP, and have now been removed and properly posted here as an answer of its own.