# How to limit element heights to specific values (“stepped”) based on content

Tags: html, css

This is a follow-up to my previous question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218973/how-to-limit-element-heights-to-specific-values-stepped-based-on-content). Is there any way to achieve, I can't describe it better, "step-based heights" on a div? I made a little [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnjetmgo/) to display what I have.

My target is now, that every box has a height that's a multiple of 400px. So if a box with height: auto; would be 345px, it should be 400px, if it's between 400 and 800px it should be 800px, and so on. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything useful to achieve this. Any ideas?

This should be achieved ONLY with HTML and CSS. A jQuery solution could look like this:

```js
$('div').each(resize);
    
function resize() {
  var height = $(this).css( "height" );
  var newHeight = Math.ceil(parseInt(height) / 400) * 400;
  $(this).css('height', newHeight+'px');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This should be achieved ONLY with html and css

Unfortunately, CSS is not a progamming language so there is no property that can achieve this.

So, basically...this impossible without JS/JQ.